# Apache no arranca con drivers sql server

Tags: sql-server, apache, xampp

Estoy intentando conectar PHP(Version 7.3) con SQL Server 2019, Descargue los drivers (SQLSRV59.EXE) de SQL Server y los instale en Xammp y modifique el archivo: "php.ini" agregando las siguientes lineas:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll
```

Pero al intentar iniciar el apache me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No creo que sea un problema de puertos puesto que corrí el Netstat y el puerto 80 y 443 no están siendo ocupados, además de que antes de agregar las 4 líneas el apache arranca sin problema, incluso con las primeras 2 (Archivos _ts):

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
```

Pero cuando agrego las otras dos(archivos _nts), me manda el error

y al consultar la versión del PHP:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los logs de errores:

```
[Thu Jun 30 18:03:26.441082 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1864:tid 568] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jun 30 18:03:26.491402 2022] [core:warn] [pid 1864:tid 568] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Jun 30 18:03:26.491402 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1864:tid 568] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

Despues de ello probe comentar y añadir las siguientes lineas en el archivo httpd-ssl-conf

```
#ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerName localhost
```

Pero me envia este log:

```
Thu Jun 30 18:06:23.423338 2022] [core:warn] [pid 10992:tid 516] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```

Alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Qué ves cuando le das clic al boton de Logs de Apache (tal y como te dice el log que hagas)? Ves algún error más específico? Por favor ve a [edit] la pregunta para responder a este y cualquier otro comentario :)